# Person Field loaded event in sharepoint forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I'm doing some customize operations on a person field in one of the forms. 
I need to fire a function once the edit form "Person" field is loaded. i tried `window.load()` but that takes too much time as the person field gets loaded long before the full page is loaded.

Is there any SP/jQuery event that tells me a form is fully loaded(as in all fields are populated with the existing values)?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

Inside document.ready()

```
var tempData = JSON.parse($('[id^="' + peoplepickerFieldInternalName + '"] input')[0].value);

                var tempHTMLValue = "";

                if (tempData.length > 0) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < tempData.length; i++) {

                        if (i === 0) {
                            tempHTMLValue = "<a class='ms-subtleLink' href='" + Your Site URL + "/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=" + tempData[i].EntityData.SPUserID + "'>" + tempData[i].DisplayText + "</a>"
                        }

                        else {
                            tempHTMLValue = tempHTMLValue + ", <a class='ms-subtleLink' href='" + Your Site URL + "/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=" + tempData[i].EntityData.SPUserID + "'>" + tempData[i].DisplayText + "</a>"
                        }
                    }
                }

                $('[id^="' + peoplepickerFieldInternalName + '"]').parent().prepend('<div style="display:block !important;">' + tempHTMLValue + '</div>');

                $('[id^="' + fieldInternalName + '"]').hide();
```

Comment: it is not working. the people picker gets resolved after DOM gets ready. which means at the time this code runs the people picker is not resolved yet.

Comment: yes,but have you got value in "tempHTMLValue" variable in document.ready()?

Comment: `tempdata` itself is not getting initialised as` input[0]` is not defined at the time of `document.ready`. so if condition never evaluates to true.

Comment: Then i think window.load() is better option.